# Assignments done in pool.connect

Tags: javascript

What does it do?
In the documentation, I do not understand the answer.

I'm not using it correctly, I get a query error from the database

```
 pool.connect(function (err, client, done) {
    if (err) console.log("connect " + err.toString());
    else
        client.query('SELECT id, "idName", "idContact", "idExperience", 
"idSkill", "dateAdded", "dateColloquy"' +
            'FROM public."applicant ";', function (err, result) {

            if (err) {
                console.log("query " + err.toString());

            }
            else {
                console.log(result.rows);
                //module.exports.res = result.rows;
            }
            done();
        });

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now there are many errors, the error you are getting from the database (sad that you don't share it with us) should be the `"dateColloquy"FROM` part. Now once you fixed that and inserted a space before `FROM`, you'll notice that all your fields are not included as data, but exactly as what you wrote - idName (literally the string), ... for every field but `id` the same.

Use backticks (```) (or nothing at all) for column names, not `"` nor `'`.

The next error you'll experience will be that you are trying to

```
module.exports.res = result.rows;
```

You can't export asynchronous retrieved data like that.

Comment: This is a separate file.
how to be, if I specify at the end of the function module.exports for app.js file, I'm using undifine.
how to transfer database data to another file?

Comment: You can with a callback and an exported function. You can't export asynchronous retrieved data with module.exports though. It's pretty much the same as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call @АнтонПрохоров and how to deal with async code. `function foo(callback) {
  setTimeout(() => callback('foo'), 1000);
}

function bar(res) {
  console.log(res);
}

foo(bar);`

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan The lib is unrelated to the question, it's good that OP has omitted to tag it. The question is about async behavior and a few syntax errors in sql query. FWI the lib seems to be node-mysql if that helps you..

Comment: Of course, you have to know that the function is asynchronous, and to know that, you need to know the library. I'm also not sure how you know that the line `module.exports.res = result.rows` is used... it's not in the question.

Comment: Take another look at the question please, also on the commented parts... @MikeMcCaughan To know that it's async it's sufficient to see all the callbacks

Comment: Mayby use this code 
    const { Pool } = require('pg') module.exports = {
      query: (text, params) => pool.query(text, params)
    }